# Can I proxy HTTP requests through another machine?

Tags: windows, networking, vpn, proxy

#### Context

I have my Windows work machine with a corporate VPN setup which allows me to connect to Databases and services in the private network.

#### Problem

I like developing on my personal Windows machine, but I do not want to install the corporate VPN on my personal device.

Can I setup a proxy/interceptor so that specific requests from my personal machine go to the private network services, proxied through my work machine?

e.g. Personal machine connects to Private DB by first calling my work machine, which simply forwards that request to the private service since the work machine is connected to the VPN.

Comment: Yes, but it is better to simply ask your IT department for a pc you can use at home.

Comment: Agreed. Also trying to use a DB over a VPN (if that will be involved) will likely damage the DB.

Comment: @John, any evidence to support your assertion about using a DB over a VPN damaging the DB.  (From someone that has done this) it sounds implausible.  First off properly designed databases should not allow a broken connection to cause damage and secondly, VPN's can be used to INCREASE the reliability of a connection - I've travelled between 2 places on different network connection hundreds of KM's apart, and the sessions I had going through my VPN continued to work uninterrupted thanks to the VPN.

Comment: any evidence to support your assertion about using a DB over a VPN damaging the DB.  ....   I have seen the happen and we have had to access the machine with the DB and run the DB client and server that way. It depends on how chatty the DB is.